# Condition for an integer exactly three primes factors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to count the number of integers `n` in the range [1, 10000] that satisfy all three of the properties below:

- `n` has exactly three prime factors
- `n + 1` is a prime number
- `n^2 + 1` is a prime number

I tried that but don't work :

```
Select[
  Range[1, 10000], 
  FactorInteger[[#] == 3] && PrimeQ[# + 1] && PrimeQ[#^2 + 1] &]
```

Comment: Change your first condition to `Length[FactorInteger[#]] == 3`.

Answer (score 4):

I interpret your question to be: find integers $n$ with exactly three prime factors such that $n+1$ is prime and $n^2+1$ is prime. See [PrimeNu](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeNu.html).

```
Select[Range[10000], PrimeNu[#] == 3 && PrimeQ[# + 1] && PrimeQ[#^2 + 1] &]
```

> {66, 126, 130, 150, 156, 180, 240, 270, 280,...,9340, 9436, 9600, 9696}

```
Count[Range[10000], _?(PrimeNu[#] == 3 && PrimeQ[# + 1] && PrimeQ[#^2 + 1] &)]
```

> 81

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I didn't know the function PrimeNu. Is there any website where I can find function like this ? 
Thanks again and have a good day

Comment: @alandelachair It's often helpful to browse [the online docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/). For instance, if you search "prime", the list of results contains "Prime Numbers (Guide)"; if you open that, one of the functions listed in that guide is `PrimeNu`.